# Problema con select dinámico

Tags: php, html, mysql, select

Hola compañeros tengo un problema con un select dinámico cargado desde una bd.
Pasa lo siguiente al momento de darle select aparecen campos en blanco pero doy inspeccionar y miro y si esta arrojando los resultados pero no se porque no se muestra en el select

```
<?php 
require_once ("php/db.php");
 $query = "SELECT * FROM student ORDER BY student";
    $resultado=$connect->query($query);
 ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="stu" class="col-sm-2 control-label">estudiante</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
       <select id="stu" name="stu">
    <option>Seleccione</option>

<?php 
   while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row['studen']; ?>"></option>

<?php } ?>

 </select>
```

Comment: El problema es que no estas poniendo nada para mostrar en los option, le das un value, pero entre <option> y </option> no pones nada. prueba así: `<option value="<?php echo $row['studen']; ?>"><?php echo $row['studen']; ?></option>`

Comment: Tienes dos problemas uno en value="<?php echo $row['studen']; ?>" te hace falta una "t" en studen, y luego te hace falta poner un texto entre los <option></option>

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un error en esta línea: `<option value="<?php echo $row['studen']; ?>"></option>` cuando debería ser así: `<option value="<?php echo $row['student']; ?>"><?php echo $row['student']; ?></option>`

Answer (score 0):

el problema es que le estas dando un value pero no estas escriviendo nada en el option deberia ser asi:

```
<option value="<?php echo $row['studen']; ?>"><?php echo $row['studen']; ?></option>
```

Comment: Gracias probare y les comento

Comment: hey que tal te funciono?